# Exponential map commutes with the projection homomorphism into Calkin algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $B(X)$ denote the space of bounded operators on a Banach space $X$ and $K(X)$ the compact operators. Let $\pi : B(X) \to B(X) / K(X)$ denote the quotient map. Let $u$ denote the right shift operator.

My question is: why does the equality $$ e^{\pi(w')}= \pi (e^{w'})$$

hold? It is on the third last line in the following example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any two Banach algebras $ A $ and $ B $, any bounded homomorphism $ \pi: A \to B $ and any element $ a \in A $, we have
\begin{align}
e^{\pi(a)} & = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \cdot [\pi(a)]^{n} \\
           & = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \cdot \pi(a^{n}) \\
           & = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \pi \! \left( \frac{1}{n!} \cdot a^{n} \right) \\
           & = \pi \! \left( \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \cdot a^{n} \right) \\
           & = \pi(e^{a}).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you!! This really helped me!